# How to show name of course in INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I have two tables: `users` and `courses`. Inside **users table** i have filed `course` where i have course id. Inside **courses table** i have just `ID` and `NAME`.

**I need to get popular course.** I do request:

```
SELECT u.course, COUNT(*) as freq FROM users u INNER JOIN courses c ON u.course = c.id GROUP BY u.course
```

As a result: id => freq. But i need to replace ID to NAME of course. How?

Thanks.

Comment: Popular course is the course which have most rows in `users` table where field `course` is id of course.

Comment: add `c.name` to the select?

Comment: It seems like there should be a third table establishing a many-to-may relationship between users and courses.

Comment: Can u add some expected data and expected result set?

Comment: @IdontDownVote wow! I did not know that it was possible to write in select also what was in joining

Comment: In newer versions of mysql, it no longer allows you to include non-aggregated columns in the select list.

Comment: not sure why you would think its not possible, add `*` and see everything your actually able to return

Comment: @Don'tPanic if true, how can i do my task?

Comment: well i wont be upgrading to that version of mysql, any time soon (EVER)

Comment: One way is to make your count query a subquery and join the subquery to the course table again.

Comment: @IdontDownVote I believe that's actually more standard SQL behavior and something MySQL has made an exception to for a while. The reason it's not generally supported is that the value of the non-aggregated column is ambiguous within the group. In some cases that doesn't matter, though.

Comment: Mysql only has it set that way by default on the new version. It can be set to its normal mode. It's a 5.7.5 change. Setting is `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

Comment: as @IdontDownVote said, add `c.name` to the `SELECT` clause, and just add it to the `GROUP BY` clause as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what database you use, but I would assume you can use CTEs since most modern databases do. Your query can be written as:

```
with x as (
  select course, count(*) as freq from users group by course
),
y as (
  select max(freq) as max_freq from x
)
select c.name, x.freq
  from x
  join y on x.freq = y.max_freq
  join courses c on c.id = x.course
```

This query has the [desirable?] side effect that it shows more than one course, if there are more than one tied in first place.

Comment: it wont work since `select course, count(*) as freq from users` needs `group by`

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov Good catch! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Add `c.name` to both the `SELECT` clause and the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT u.course, c.name, COUNT(*) as freq
FROM users u
INNER JOIN courses c
ON u.course = c.id
GROUP BY u.course, c.name;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=02a41e0f1e6407e516e91c49b4bdc1d2

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT u.course, COUNT(*) as freq, c.name FROM users u INNER JOIN courses c ON u.course = c.id GROUP BY u.course
```

Comment: @HarshaB select course if from users, count rows and named as freq and course name from course table.
Then i need to INNER JOIN course table where i want to find course id equal in user table field course id

Comment: The comment was the part of review quality of answer. I was not looking for your answer, just checking the quality of answer. You can edit your answer and can add the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

If your DBMS supports `row_number` this will be suitable:

```
select t.id, c.name, t.cnt  
    from course c
    join (
        select c.id, count(1) cnt, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by count(1) desc) rn
          from users u 
          join course c on c.id = u.course
        group by id
        )t on t.id = c.id and t.rn = 1
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you should include some explanation with the code to make the answer more useful.